# Date comparison in shell script

Tags: shell

In my script to monitor expiry date of .der certificates, I managed to take out the expiry date of the certificate but when I compare with the current date, its not happening. The expiry date has m/d/yy format, I compared that with current date of the same format(mm/dd/yy) its failing. When I grep the expiry date, is the result has the same date format or it changes to string?  Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

```
d=7/7/11
dd=$(IFS=/; printf "%02d/%02d/%02d" $d)
echo $dd  # => 07/07/11
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting this error while executing the above. -bash: fg: %02d/%02d/%02d: no such job. Any clues?

Comment: Hmm, did you cut and paste exactly?

Comment: It worked. I had made a mistake, corrected it later, its working. Thank you Mr. Jackman.

Comment: Hi I tried the following code: export c5=`date +"%m/%d/%y"`; if [ $c4 -le $c5 ]; then echo "Success" fi. (c4 is the expiry date of the cert)Error "integer expression expected" is thrown. Anything wrong with this piece of code?

Comment: "-le" is for numeric comparison -- use "<" for string comparison. Also, if you're going to be comparing dates as strings like this, you really need to use yyyy/mm/dd format: `[[ "01/01/2011" < "12/31/2010" ]] && echo the future is lesser`